# How important is an Honors Thesis for MSW programs?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, thesis, research-undergraduate

I plan on applying to grad school for social work, but wasn't sure about the general expectations for prospective MSW students. It seems like overall, I would be considered more competitive with an honors thesis; however, would I then be considered less competitive if I chose not to do one? I have research experience since sophomore year of college and will be doing an independent research project this summer through a program called McNair Scholars. I was hesitant about the honors thesis because a) I have yet to find an advisor and we are expected to have one by the spring term before our last year (which is now for me) and b) I wanted to study abroad in the fall meaning I would be ineligible for an honors thesis since I am expected to enroll in a year-long course for it.

Comment: Have you tried asking the admissions office of the grad school you want to apply to?

Comment: It would probably be helpful to be looking for an advisor regardless.  S/he can help with many aspects of your study and your strategizing.  There are questions and answers that address the finding of an advisor.